# SQL - Query by Date and Add number of Days

Tags: sql, date

I am trying to write a script that let's me run a query plus 10 days(or any date really) from the current date. I am having the hardest time trying to find a solution.

Here is what I am using currently for the date portion:

```
AND dersape_id BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20130110'
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which SQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Date Add function depending on which SQL Platform you are using.

DATEADD() in SQL Server

DATE_ADD() in MySQL